# Is there any way to match a request with response using Hydra and Typhoeus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typhoeus

Is there any way to match a request URL with the response body for that URL?

I'm using Hydra for GET requests, and the item ID appears in the URL, but not the response body, just the details about that item. 100 HTTP requests are send off fine, but I can't sort the responses.

My alternative is use OpenUri and send requests 1 at a time.

```
products.each do |list|
 url = www.example.com/list.id
 hydra.queue(request)
 request.on_complete do |response|
  if response.body["price"] != list_all.find(request.id?).price
   puts "I can't tell which response goes to which request"
  end
 end
end
```

Solution

```
response.effective_url
```

Answer (score 6):

Everything's there, but you need to dig around in the response received by Hydra.

For instance:

```
require 'typhoeus'

request = Typhoeus::Request.new(
  'www.example.net',
  method: :get,
  headers: { Accept: 'text/html' }
)

hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.hydra
hydra.queue(request)
hydra.run
```

Here's the response and inside it is the original request:

```
response = request.response
response.request
# => #<Typhoeus::Request:0x007f9093f9f288
#     @base_url="www.example.net",
#     @hydra=
#      #<Typhoeus::Hydra:0x007f9093f9f0d0
#       @max_concurrency=200,
#       @memory={},
#       @multi=
#        #<Ethon::Multi:0x007f9093f9f030
#         @easy_handles=[],
#         @fd_excep=#<Ethon::Curl::FDSet:0x007f9093f9eba8>,
#         @fd_read=#<Ethon::Curl::FDSet:0x007f9093f9ed60>,
#         @fd_write=#<Ethon::Curl::FDSet:0x007f9093f9ec48>,
#         @handle=#<FFI::AutoPointer address=0x007f9095c74740>,
#         @max_fd=#<FFI::MemoryPointer address=0x007f9094f484d0 size=4>,
#         @running_count=0,
#         @timeout=#<FFI::MemoryPointer address=0x007f9094f3a7e0 size=8>, # !> instance variable @on_body not initialized
#         @timeval=#<Ethon::Curl::Timeval:0x007f9093f9ee78>>,
#       @options={},
#       @queued_requests=[]>,
#     @on_complete=[],
#     @on_headers=[],
#     @on_success=[],
#     @options=
#      {:method=>:get,
#       :headers=>
#        {"User-Agent"=>"Typhoeus - https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus",
#         :Accept=>"text/html"},
#       :maxredirs=>50},
#     @original_options={:method=>:get, :headers=>{:Accept=>"text/html"}},
#     @response=
#      #<Typhoeus::Response:0x007f9093f97d08
#       @options=
#        {:httpauth_avail=>0,
#         :total_time=>0.11088,
#         :starttransfer_time=>0.110587,
#         :appconnect_time=>0.0,
#         :pretransfer_time=>0.053747,
#         :connect_time=>0.053611,
#         :namelookup_time=>0.001304,
#         :effective_url=>"HTTP://www.example.net/",
#         :primary_ip=>"93.184.216.34",
#         :response_code=>200,
#         :request_size=>121,
#         :redirect_count=>0,
#         :return_code=>:ok,
#         :response_headers=>
#          "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nCache-Control: max-age=604800\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nDate: Tue, 30 Dec 2014 19:24:10 GMT\r\nEtag: \"359670651\"\r\nExpires: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 19:24:10 GMT\r\nLast-Modified: Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT\r\nServer: ECS (cpm/F9FC)\r\nX-Cache: HIT\r\nx-ec-custom-error: 1\r\nContent-Length: 1270\r\n\r\n",
#         :response_body=>
#          "<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\" />\n    <style type=\"text/css\">\n    body {\n        background-color: #f0f0f2;\n        margin: 0;\n        padding: 0;\n        font-family: \"Open Sans\", \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n        \n    }\n    div {\n        width: 600px;\n        margin: 5em auto;\n        padding: 50px;\n        background-color: #fff;\n        border-radius: 1em;\n    }\n    a:link, a:visited {\n        color: #38488f;\n        text-decoration: none;\n    }\n    @media (max-width: 700px) {\n        body {\n            background-color: #fff;\n        }\n        div {\n            width: auto;\n            margin: 0 auto;\n            border-radius: 0;\n            padding: 1em;\n        }\n    }\n    </style>    \n</head>\n\n<body>\n<div>\n    <h1>Example Domain</h1>\n    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this\n    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>\n    <p><a href=\"http://www.iana.org/domains/example\">More information...</a></p>\n</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n",
#         :debug_info=>
#          #<Ethon::Easy::DebugInfo:0x007f9093f9de60 @messages=[]>},
#       @request=#<Typhoeus::Request:0x007f9093f9f288 ...>>>
```

Inside there is the request's `base_url`:

```
response.request.base_url
# => "www.example.net"
```

And the `effective_url`:

```
response.effective_url 
# => "HTTP://www.example.net/"
```

If I remember right, the first is what you asked for, and the second is what you got after redirects were processed, i.e. where you really landed.

Answer (score 0):

You still have access to the `list` variable, so couldn't you just get it from there? Like:

```
  products.each do |list|
    url = www.example.com/list.id
    hydra.queue(request)
    request.on_complete do |response|
      puts "#{list.id}, #{response.body}"
    end
  end
```